# Complicated example of Table manipulation in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a table with two columns:

1. timestamp of comments when a customer asked a question (Waiting for our Customer Support)
2. timestamp when the customer agent replied (Waiting for a customer) or (Scheduled).

Perfect case scenario would be: a customer ask a question and then customer support write back. But you as you see in the example, there are many cases when customers write many comments consecutively or customer agents write many comments consecutively as well.

My goal is to transform the table into another format (Green table in the screenshot). But first, the challenge would be to set logic for when comments "start" and "end".

raw data: https://filebin.net/b12thdimcia73646

[image: comment_id and status_id screenshot]

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

Comment: Is there a comment id of some sort? A way to identify the comments in data so we can then isolate the Start and End of each comment?

Comment: no unfortunately not :/

Comment: Ok, so how do you know which comment no relates to which "Comments Inserted"?

Comment: Thanks alot @AndyTARSols  for your quick response. I managed to get the comment_id and also status_id.
Please see screenshot above and i also added the raw  data example . 

Do you think doing this in SQL would make it easier ? and do you know how please? I was thinking with Lag function ?

Comment: Perhaps my point is badly made. In one of your tables it has TO DO Comments, which appears to group comments to some form of event. It's this event identification I'm interested in. How do you know which comment ids are related to what event?

Comment: Still how can anyone deduce that comment1 pertains to same record when `comment id` of both these are different?